# Circular Dependency in two dialogs

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two dialogs, SignIn and SignUp.

SignIn has the option to SignUp, where I wanna close the SignIn dialog and open the SignUp dialog.

Also, SignUp has the option to SignIn, where I wanna close the SignUp dialog and open the SignIn dialog.

I have successfully achieved this through the following component codes. However, I am getting a waring of circular dependency in my console. Any suggestions to handle this better and get rid of circular dependency.

sign-in.component.ts

```
signup() {
  this.closeModal();
  this.dialog.open(SignUpComponent);
}
```

sign-up.component.ts

```
signin() {
  this.closeModal();
  this.dialog.open(SignInComponent);
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the modal in the parent's component and emit the call to open a specific modal to that parent:

```
@Output() openSignup = new EventEmitter();

<button (click)="openSignup.emit()">
```

The parent will listen to changes from all its modal children and handle them and the children will not know anything of each other, preventing circular dependencies.

Comment: I have a link `<a (openSignup)="signup()" (click)="signin()">Login</a>`, but this is not workin

Comment: You should read this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. It explains why something (I don't know what) is not working for you. The answer to your question is to keep your app's layout hierarchical = pyramide-shaped. siblings should not know anything of each other but the parent should do the delegating.